# find word and wrap div

Tags: jquery, text

I don't have access to the HTML, only the raw text. Is it possible to find a word in the raw text like INFO and ENDINFO and use those to wrap a div around the content.

```
<div>
content content content content content

INFO
Information content information content

ENDINFO
</div>

<div>
content content content content content

    <div class="INFO">
    Information content information content

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hiya yep use `.find` to find the word and use `.prepend` when you find that word http://api.jquery.com/prepend/ hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: What a strange situation. This seems like an instance where you should really be looking at the preprocess that is generating this string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
<div id="content">
content content content content content

INFO
Information content information content

ENDINFO
</div>

<div>
content content content content content

    <div class="INFO">
    Information content information content

    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document)ready(function(){
    var content = $('#content').html();
    var regex = /INFO.*ENDINFO/gi;
    var info = content.match(regex);

    $('.INFO').html(info);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank looks really complicated. I have never used regex. Thanks! Works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Question has already been answered, but I've created a 'search highlighter' in the past. It might come in handy: http://jsfiddle.net/KeesCBakker/nSb6b/